# Javascript unusual behavior regarding Array containing 1...N using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

In Javascript, I make this simple ascending array by spread operator.

```
[...Array(5).keys()]
// printed list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I simply added 1 and this unexpected array generated.
(I just expected it would be an error)

```
[...Array(5).keys() + 1] 
// printed list
["[", "o", "b", "j", "e", "c", "t", " ", "A", "r", "r", "a", "y", " ", "I", "t", "e", "r", "a", "t", "o", "r", "]", "1"]
```

I would like to know what makes this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the expression to the right of the `...` is evaluated. That is, `Array(5).keys() + 1` gets evaluated, and the result of that evaluation is then spread. Grouping the expression may make things a little clearer:

```
[...(Array(5).keys() + 1)]
```

So, above, we start with calculating the result of `Array(5).keys() + 1`. The `+` operator works between primitive operands. When you do `Array(5).keys()` you get an iterator back which is not classified as a primitive. So, JS will try and convert it to a primitive. When JS tries to convert the iterator into a primitive in this context it tries to:

1. Invoke the iterator's [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/@@toPrimitive) method, since this doesn't exist, it moves onto trying the next step
2. Invoke the `.valueOf()` method of the iterator. This succeeds, but it returns the iterator back, which is not a primitive, so we go to the next step
3. Invoke the `.toString()` method. This results in a non-object type (ie: a string), and so this is successful.

When the iterator's `.toString()` method is called it gets evaluated to `"[object Array Iterator]"`. As this then gets added with the number `1`, we concatenate the string with the number (rather than add), giving:

```
[..."[object Array Iterator]1"]
```

Since strings are iterable, the spread syntax will use the string's iterator to loop through the code points in the string, resulting in every character of the string becoming its own element:

```
["[", "o", "b", "j", "e", "c", "t", " ", "A", "r", "r", "a", "y", " ", "I", "t", "e", "r", "a", "t", "o", "r", "]", "1"]
```

In order to add one to each item in your iterator, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which can take an iterator, and applies a mapping function to each element:

```js
const res = Array.from(Array(5).keys(), i => i+1);
console.log(res);
```

Since the argument to Array.from() doesn't have to be an iterator, you could also just use `Array(5)` instead and use the index as the value to add to:

```js
const res = Array.from(Array(5), (_,i) => i+1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add + 1 it will handle the return from ...Array(5).keys() as a string.
Look at these additional examples:

console.log(Array(5).keys())
outputs:
[object Array Iterator]

console.log(Array(5).keys() + 1)
outputs:
[object Array Iterator]1

console.log(...Array(5).keys() + 1)
outputs:
[ o b j e c t   A r r a y   I t e r a t o r ] 1

Answer (score 0):

it is as you typed `[...(Array(5).keys() + 1)]` which mean the `+` has precedence over `...`

Answer (score 0):

Read more about the types conversion in JavaScript when using different operators

to simplify the answer, if you try to do `Object() + 1`, you'll get `"[object Object]1"`, it can't be converted to a number, JS converts the `Object()` to a string, you can get the same by doing `String(Object())`,

in your example, `Array(5).keys()` is an object that inherits from Array Iterator, so when converted to a string you get `"[object Array Iterator]"` and of course by adding 1 you get `"[object Array Iterator]1"`, and it's now a string, if you use spread operator for it it will be splitted to characters, which is an expected result for your example

instead, to add 1, you can do: `[...Array(5).keys()].map(i=> i+1)`